# Would a liquid propellant fire in Mars' atmosphere cause charring?

Tags: mars, atmosphere, liquid-fuel, fire

If a ship carrying liquid propellant crashed on the surface of Mars, rupturing all tanks, I assume the propellant could ignite.

If the propellant did ignite might it leave indications of charring on any of the debris?

Comment: "Ignite" suggests a reaction with the local atmosphere, which is unlikely. A monoprellant might explode in response to shock/heating etc. in the crash. Otherwise the various components of the propellant might react with one another for a while before they disperse. Partial combustion could lead to residual carbon for some fuels, which could be left as charring.

Comment: Well we do find charring on all the recent landing sites on Mars...

Comment: A very hot object or flame might decompose atmospheric CO2 and produce soot, or the heat might lead some materials on the surface of the ship to "char" my losing volatile elements.